# Unable to get reliable boolean value when start/stop services

Tags: windows, vbscript, wmi

Hi I'm having a few issues attempting to add reliability to part of a script I'm doing.

I've created a `sub` to query a service, it first checks if the service is running & then stops said service. I've tried a few different methods to check if the service is running via WMI, but I'm getting unreliable results when I've attempted to use `objSrvc.Started` to produce a boolean value, but this is proving unreliable, when it reaches the point in the script that the service has successfully been stopped and then querying via the `Started` method continues to return `True` or `False` depending on the state of the service when the `Started` method is first used.

```
Dim objReg : Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\"& strServer &"\root\default:StdRegProv")
Dim objFso : Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objShll : Set objShll = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Dim objSrvCnsl : Set objSrvCnsl = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

'File for output of data for testing purposes
'Set objOutFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\temp\Output.txt")

Function strSrcvName()
    strRegPth = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services"
    objReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strRegPth, arrReg

    For Each strSubKey in arrReg
        WScript.Interactive = False
        Wscript.echo strSubKey
        WScript.Interactive = True
        strFullKey = strRegPth &"\"& strSubKey
        objReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strFullKey , "DisplayName", strAppName
        On Error Resume Next
        'Test output of strAppName relates to DisplayName, REG_SZ value
        'objOutFile.Write strAppName
        'objOutFile.Write strSubKey
        If strAppName = strSrvcIn Then Exit For     
    next
    strSrcvName = strSubKey
End Function

'Wscript.Echo "Step 2"


Set objSrvc = objSrvCnsl.Get("Win32_Service.Name='"& strSrcvName & "'")
Sub objStpStrtSrvc()

If objSrvc.Started = True then
    intSrvcStt = objSrvc.StopService()
    If intSrvcStt = 0 then Wscript.Echo "Service has been stopped"
    Elseif intSrvcStt = 2 then Wscript.Echo "Insufficient privileges"
    Elseif intSrvcStt > 2 then Wscript.Echo "There is an issue, investigate"
End if
Wscript.sleep(500)
If objSrvc.Started = False then     
    intSrvcStt = objSrvc.StartService()
    If intSrvcStt = 0 then Wscript.Echo "Service has been started"
    Elseif intSrvcStt = 2 then  Wscript.Echo "Insufficient privileges"
    Elseif intSrvcStt > 2 then  Wscript.Echo "There is an issue, investigate"
End If
End Sub
```

Can someone explain to me why my variable is not having its value updated when the service state changes?

I apologise if this isn't clear enough. I have found an alternative method but it isn't very fault tolerant (tbh neither is what I'm wanting to do, but it's early days there is still a lot to be added), I stopped the service waited 500ms, which after checking if the service was in the `stopping` state, if it wasn't then it called upon the new `sub` to start the service.

```
Sub objStpStrtSrvc()

If objSrvc.Started = True then
    intSrvcStt = objSrvc.StopService()
    If intSrvcStt = 0 then Wscript.Echo "Service has been stopped"
    Elseif intSrvcStt = 2 then Wscript.Echo "Insufficient privileges"
    Elseif intSrvcStt > 2 then Wscript.Echo "There is an issue, investigate"
End if

If objSrvc.Status = "Stopping" then
    Wscript.Sleep(500)
    If objSrvc.Status = "Stopping" then
        Wscript.Sleep(500)
        If objSrvc.Status = "Stopping" then
            Wscript.Sleep(500)
            If objSrvc.Status = "Stopping" then
                Wscript.Sleep(5000)
                objStart()
            End If
        Elseif objSrvc.Status = "OK" then
            objStart()
        End If
    Elseif objSrvc.Status = "OK" then
        objStart()
    End If
Elseif objSrvc.Status = "OK" then
    objStart()
End If
End Sub

Sub objStart()
    intSrvcStt = objSrvc.StartService()
    If intSrvcStt = 0 then Wscript.Echo "Service has been started"
    Elseif intSrvcStt = 2 then Wscript.Echo "Insufficient privileges"
    Elseif intSrvcStt > 2 then Wscript.Echo "There is an issue, investigate"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Pretty unclear what kind of object `objSrvc` might be.  But the basic conclusion to draw is that StopService() only *initiates* a stop.  It can take a while for a service to actually stop, taking 30 seconds to get there isn't unusual.  So sleeping for 500 msec just doesn't get the job done, you have to spin until the status is not "Stopping" anymore.  Your nested If-statements are not good enough, you need While.

Comment: The service I'm working with currently (purely for testing locally) is showing as stopped on the properties window. My initial test had wait at 30 seconds, as my first thought was the same as yourself, but as I noticed how quickly the service was terminating I reduced it much further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

It's been explained to me that I need to call the service object again, to refresh it's attributes.

```
Sub objStpStrtSrvc()

If objSrvc.Started then
    objSrvc.StopService()
    intSrvcStt = objSrvc.StopService()
    Wscript.Echo "Stopping Service"
    If intSrvcStt = 0 then Wscript.Echo "Service has been stopped"
    Elseif intSrvcStt = 2 then Wscript.Echo "Insufficient privileges"
    Elseif intSrvcStt > 2 then Wscript.Echo "There is an issue, investigate"
End if
wscript.sleep 500
wscript.echo intSrvcStt

Set objSrvc = objSrvCnsl.Get("Win32_Service.Name='"& strDerp & "'")
If not objSrvc.Started then
    wscript.echo "Got Here2"
    'intSrvcStt = objSrvc.StartService()
    objSrvc.StartService()
    Wscript.Echo "Starting Service"
    If intSrvcStt = 0 then Wscript.Echo "Service has been started"
    Elseif intSrvcStt = 2 then  Wscript.Echo "Insufficient privileges"
    Elseif intSrvcStt > 2 then  Wscript.Echo "There is an issue, investigate"
End If
End Sub
```